# Mocked 404 preventing $http promise resolution/rejection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory which wraps `$http` for custom template loading, and I'm trying to write unit tests for it. Valid templates work because they're pre-loaded into `$templateCache`, so the underlying http promise never needs to be called.

However, I'm trying to test our promise gets rejected if the file path is wrong.

I'm telling ngMock to respond with a 404:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/invalid').respond(404, '');
```

My test never fires the `then/catch/finally` code. The underlying http promise is never resolved/rejected.

I've reduced the test to pure `$http` calls while resolving this issue.

```
it('"get" rejects with invalid path', function(done) {
    var deferred = $http.get('/invalid');
    deferred.catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        done(error);
    });

    deferred.then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        done();
    });

    deferred.finally(function() {
        console.log('finally!');
    });

    // Trigger http promise resolution
    $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: No it's using Mocha/Chai. This particular test is in a Karma environment with PhantomJS

Comment: Yes, I actually am using $rootScope.$digest() at the bottom of the method, same with the valid template paths, but nothing resolves.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit, because the valid files comes from $templateCache, so the issue is how to force $http to resolve promises when I'm mocking them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger the responses to requests, call `$httpBackend.flush();`. This will also trigger a digest cycle, so you won't need to call `.$apply();`.

Also, the response from an `$http` is a modified promise. I've updated the code below to handle your use case.

Lastly, make sure that you are using the `ngMock` module and not the `ngMockE2E`. They each give you a slightly different `$httpBackend` object, but the `ngMock` module is meant for unit testing. See the differences here ([`ngMock`'s `$httpBackend`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) vs [`ngMockE2E`'s `$httpBackend`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend))

[Here is a simplified fiddle showing how it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/nphumx1v/1/)

Your updated code would be:

```
it('"get" rejects with invalid path', function() {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/invalid').respond(404, '');

    var wasRejected = false;

    $http.get('/invalid')
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
        wasRejected = true;
      });

    // Trigger http promise resolution
    $httpBackend.flush();

    // Make your assertion...
    expect(wasRejected).toBeTrue();
});

afterEach(function(){
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Comment: This errors with `Error: No pending request to flush !`

Comment: Then that means your mocked $httpBackend is not set up correctly. Consider specifying the handlers from within the test. (call `$httpBackend.when('GET', '/invalid').respond(404, '');` before `$http.get('/invalid');`).

Comment: I believe $httpBackend.when('GET', '/invalid').respond(404, ''); needs to go inside your it() at the very top. Before you make the $http request.

Comment: The backend mock is in my `beforeEach`. It doesn't have any impact by moving it into the `it` method.

Comment: I've updated the code to include a call to `.expectGET()`, as most of the Angular examples have.

Comment: I've added it too, but no luck. Same "no pending request to flush" error.

Comment: I already have the `afterEach` block. I tried commenting them out as well, in case they were causing an issue, but no luck.

Comment: I've done a major update to the example code, as well as added a link to [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nphumx1v/1/).

Comment: I'm not sure where things are failing then. I've updated my test to use the same setup: https://pste.me/#/06oSd - though I actually have this in a testing framework. I still see `No pending request to flush !`

Comment: I see what the problem is, you are using the `ngMockE2E` module. `$httpBackend` for unit testing only works with `ngMock`. Once you switch that over it should work fine. [Here is the updated code you pasted.](https://pste.me/#/Cutmr)

Comment: @helion3 Any luck after using `ngMock` instead of `ngMockE2E`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems with your code. First $http promises are resolved using success, error and then. From the angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

$http Returns a promise object with the standard then method and two http specific methods: success and error. The then method takes two arguments a success and an error callback which will be called with a response object. The success and error methods take a single argument - a function that will be called when the request succeeds or fails respectively. The arguments passed into these functions are destructured representation of the response object passed into the then method.

The second is that you need to call $httpBackend.flush(); to trigger the return of your request. This is to simulate an asynchronous behavior in a synchronous test.

```
it('Should return status Not Found', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/invalid').respond(404, 'Not Found');
        var result = '';
        $http.get('/invalid')
            .success(function(data){
                result = data;
            }).error(function(reason){
                result = reason;
            });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result).toEqual('Not Found');
    });
});
```

Comment: I only used `http` for testing, but then/catch etc work fine outside of this context. As stated in another answer's comment thread, `flush` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the code you're actually trying to test?

Comment: I've already updated my question with the http code which fails.